# Named pipe communication between C# server and C++ client

Tags: c#, c++, named-pipes

I have a C# server and a C++ client. The C# server works just fine as I tested it with a C# client and all the messages from the client were properly transferred to the server. However, when implementing the C++ client, I seem to run into certain issues.

First of all, this is my C# server:

```
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    NamedPipeServerStream server = new NamedPipeServerStream(name);
                    server.WaitForConnection();

                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(server);

                    Console.WriteLine("Client connected");

                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (reader.ReadLine() != null)
                            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
                    }
                });
```

The `name` variable is passed as a parameter to the method.
My C++ code is the following:

```
HANDLE hPipe;
    DWORD dwWritten;

    hPipe = CreateFile(TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\testpipe"),
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL);
    if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        WriteFile(hPipe,
            "Hello Pipe\n",
            12,   // = length of string + terminating '\0' !!!
            &dwWritten,
            NULL);

        CloseHandle(hPipe);
    }
```

The server's output is the following:

```
[PIPE] Client connected
[PIPE]
```

Anyone got any suggestion? Perhaps I am going by this all wrong, as I am totally new at pipes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried flushing the file buffers before closing the handle on the C++ side? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364439(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have added FlushFileBuffers(hPipe) after calling WriteFile() but still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to diagnose code, especially network code, without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. But your server's C# code does have at least one glaring problem:

```
while (true)
{
    if (reader.ReadLine() != null)
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
}
```

Here, you first read a line from the stream, and then if it's not `null`, you read *another* line and display that. This means you are discarding every other line being sent.

The loop should probably look more like this:

```
string line;

while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

I don't understand how your C# client worked. Maybe it was incorrectly implemented as well, preceding the desired lines with blank lines to balance out the bug in the server code.

Comment: That actually fixed the entire issue. I found the C# code somewhere on Codeproject and assumed it was working properly. Thanks a bunch.